# How to load a specific stylesheet for a specific media port. and not to load other stylesheets listed in the <head>

Tags: mobile, responsive-design, media-queries

I am creating a website which is responsive, but not responsive from scratch. So I am creating another stylesheet for mobile devices.

My question is is it possible to load a stylesheet for mobile only.

Ex:

```
Stylesheet1.css (for desktops)
Stylesheet2.css (for mobiles)
```

Now, I don't want to load `stylesheet1.css` on mobiles.

Comment: I understand that everyone is not a native English speaker, but I'm still curious about all the misspellings and grammatical mistakes in questions, even their titles. For instance, here we had (before editing) the word "spefici". What combination of neuronal misfirings could result in that misspelling for "specific"? Do posters ever view their questions after they're posted to make sure there are not glaring, obvious errors? If posters do not take this basic level of care with their questions, then what level of care are they taking with their programs? `</rant>` Also, what is a "media port"?

Comment: torazaburo, i regret for what has happened. Frankly, i am getting lot of help from here and from now onwards i'll take care of the above listed things before posting questions. And i am happy that someone has showed me the mirror :-)

Answer (score 0):

if you're using PHP, you can make use of [HTTP_USER_AGENT](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

and create conditionals to load specific stylesheet..

this could be a good [example](http://www.developphp.com/page.php?id=310)